# get div height with the scroll? jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to get a div height, but this height must be the total height, with the scroll content.

for example:

```
var a = $('#rightinbox').height();
alert(a);
```

it will give me the div height but not the content inside height.

https://jsfiddle.net/h62vm38a/

How can I get the div inside content height? with the scroll?
thank you friends!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Element.scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight)** to get the height including scroll content:

```
var a = $('#rightinbox')[0].scrollHeight;
```

or:

```
var a = $('#rightinbox').prop('scrollHeight');
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rmb6d2ye/)